# django queryset custom annotate(counting)

Tags: django

i'm trying to query in django.
my model is below

```
class Game(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

my situation:

```
Game(name='League of Legend')
Game(name='StartCraft')
Game(name='OverWatch')

word_list = ["league", "over", "craft", "legend"]
games = Game.objects.annotate(word_count=blablabla).order_by('-word_count')
```

desired result queryset:

```
Gmae('League of Legend', 2)
Game('StartCraft', 1)
Game('OverWatch', 1)
```

there is solution?? :)